# Simplest example with py4J

Tags: java, python, py4j

I installed `py4J` using pip on my `conda` virtual environment in Python.  I wrote a super simple example `AdditionApplication.java` to test `py4J`, but it fails to compile, i.e.

`javac AdditionApplication.java`

fails complaining that  `GatewayServer` is not defined.

I am knowledgeable in Python but unfortunately not in Java. What else do I need to provide?

```
public class AdditionApplication {

  public int addition(int first, int second) {
    return first + second;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AdditionApplication app = new AdditionApplication();
    // app is now the gateway.entry_point
    GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer(app);
    server.start();
  }
}
```

In case it matters I have the following version of Java installed:

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

### Update 1

After I added: `import py4j.GatewayServer;` to the top of the file, I got a different error:

`package py4j does not exist`

### Update 2

`pip install py4j` left a `jar` file under `<PATH_TO_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT>/share/py4j/py4j0.8.1.jar`. I have added it to my class path with:

```
javac -cp <PATH_TO_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT>/share/py4j/py4j0.8.1.jar AdditionApplication.java
```

and it output

`AdditionApplication.class`

How do I run it?

## Final update and solution:

After applying the previous fixes, I finally run the code with:

```
java -cp <PATH_TO_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT>/share/py4j/py4j0.8.1.jar AdditionApplication
```

the code runs in the background. To test it:

```
>>> from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
>>> gateway = JavaGateway()                   # connect to the JVM
>>> random = gateway.jvm.java.util.Random()   # create a java.util.Random instance
>>> number1 = random.nextInt(10)              # call the Random.nextInt method
>>> number2 = random.nextInt(10)
>>> print(number1,number2)
(2, 7)
>>> addition_app = gateway.entry_point        # get the AdditionApplication instance
>>> addition_app.addition(number1,number2)    # call the addition method
```

Comment: I don't get it. I did exactly what you did here, but when I run: java -cp py4j0.10.8.1.jar AdditionApplication, I receive the following error:" Error: Could not find or load main class AdditionApplication". Any ideas?

Comment: For Mac/LInux:
java -cp /usr/local/share/py4j/py4j0.10.5.jar :. AdditionApplication​

For Windows:
java -cp /usr/local/share/py4j/py4j0.10.5.jar AdditionApplication

Comment: @Chiel a bit late to the party but i had the same issue today. You also need to include the folder which contains `AdditionApplication.class` to the classpath. On windows this worked for me: `java -cp ".;C:\tools\miniconda3\envs\circe\share\py4j\py4j0.10.9.7.jar" AdditionApplication`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import `GatewayServer` from the `py4j` package so that the unqualified class can be used in the application

```
import py4j.GatewayServer;
```

Comment: Thanks - I now get the error `package py4j does not exist`, but I installed py4j using `pip install py4j` from Python.

Comment: you need to include the `py4j0.x.jar` JAR file on your compile classpath, e.g. `javac -cp /usr/share/py4j/py4j0.x.jar:. AdditionApplication.java`

Comment: Thanks! The command now compiles to `AdditionApplication.class`. I imagine that in order to use it from Python it has to be running, since it's technically a server. How do I run it?

Comment: Never used p4j TBH - try `java -cp /usr/share/py4j/py4j0.x.jar:. AdditionApplication`

Comment: Thanks @Reimeus - When I run `javac ...` without the `.class` suffix, I got: `error: Class names, 'AdditionApplication' are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested`

Comment: Thanks Reimeus - That worked! I understand these were basic Java questions - I appreciate it.

Comment: @user815423426 I tried doing the exact steps you did. I'm grateful you explained how you troubleshooted how to get your code working on Java and it did on mine too! ... 

but when I attempted to test it on the python interpreter, typing "from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway" made the python interpreter complain of an ImportError even when I added the py4j onto the PYTHONPATH (using import sys .. sys.path.append("..")

help please?

Comment: nvm i found out why all i needed to do was install setup.py from the interpreter like this : **python setup.py install --user**